# What trackpad gestures does Safari support?

Tags: safari, trackpad, multi-touch

Which trackpad gestures does Safari support, and what do those gestures do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, Safari supports pinch to change zooming, three finger swipes to navigate back and forward and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Jitouch](https://www.jitouch.com/index.php?page=jitouch) to add a slew of extra gestures to Safari, and window controls in general.

[image]

Comment: JiTouch, exactly.